# does text contained in arguments to a javascript function get targeted as keywords for search engines?

Tags: javascript, seo

I am doing seo for a certain web page.  The page contains a script tag which calls a javascript function defined in an external javascript file.  The function takes an object as an argument which has text relevant to the page topic.  So the script looks like this:

```
<script>
  javascriptFunction({"aKey": ["imagefile.jpg", "some text here which will be displayed in the browser"], "bKey": ["anotherimage.jpg", "more text"]});
</script>
```

Will Google use the text in the function argument as keywords to determine the relevancy of this page to particular searches?  Would the above text "some text here which will be displayed in the browser" affect google search results in any way?

Thanks for any insights

Comment: short answer: no, not reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Oops. Was looking at custom search, not indexing!

`Google` can read comments in JS/AJAX, but everything in your JavaScript is not subject to indexing.

http://searchengineland.com/google-can-now-execute-ajax-javascript-for-indexing-99518